# Macbook keyboard gestures on windows 10

Tags: macos, mac, windows-10, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I have a late 2009 Macbook Pro with Windows 10 and `Boot Camp v. 4.0`.
Before the Windows 10 install, my Boot Camp version was working fine with Windows 8.
What do I have to do to get my Macbook keyboard gestures to work again? If it's even possible?

I cannot upgrade Boot Camp through `Apple Software Update`.
The newest `Boot Camp` version which comes with `El Capitan` or `Yosemite` is listed as not supported on my 2009 model.

Comment: I have a 2013 Macbook Air & I was having these issues too. I had to find an  old version of Bootcamp then update it using Apple Software Update and it (finally) worked. Your 09 Macbook Pro should be compatible though.

Comment: @Insane How did you manage to update with Apple Software Update? Did it appear on the list? It doesn't show on mine.

Comment: I had to like manually download it somehow. Ugh I totally forget now. I'll see if I can find the article I read

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to give [trackpad++](http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/) a look. It was designed or this situation

Comment: Very cool! But it looks like it's for the trackpad only.